# How to fix this list index out of range error

Tags: python-3.x

I want to perform column subtraction. for example [[0,2],[2,5],[3,11]] for this I want to perform (5-2),(11-5). then find which has the maximum difference.so for that I created a dictionary and store the differences along with its pair. for example difference of (5-2) is stored with 0, and difference of (11-5) is stored with 2.

error is :

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/home/viki/Music/keypress.py", line 14, in 
>       keypressTime(l)   File "/home/viki/Music/keypress.py", line 10, in keypressTime
>       d = x[i+1][1] - x[i][1] IndexError: list index out of range

```
import operator

l = [[0,2],[2.4],[0,8],[3,9],[5,20]]

def keypressTime(x):
    dic = {}
    d = 0
    for i in range(len(x)-1):
        if i <(len(x)-1):
            d = x[i+1][1] - x[i][1]
            dic["i"] = d
    return max(dict.items(),key=operator.itemgetter(1))[0]

keypressTime(l)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a typo in the variable declaration of l.
l = [[0,2],**[2.4]**,[0,8],[3,9],[5,20]]  -> change 2.4 to 2,4

And dict.items() should probably be dic.items()